Selecting and inputting text in an element by using selenium
I'm trying to automate zoom joining process using selenium.
Screenshot of the element
Here's the HTML code for the input element:
<input id="input-for-name" type="text" class="preview-meeting-info-field-input"
  autocomplete="off" required="" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="error-for-name"
  value="">

It's mandatory to input name there in order to proceed further.
I can't select and input my name on the above element. I tried by using XPATH
//*[@id="input-for-name"]

I've also tried CSS SELECTOR and nothing worked. It gives an error that the xpath id was not found in the given time frame. (I already increased time frame till 1 min, It didn't work).
My code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


service = Service("msedgedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)

try:
    driver.get("https://app.zoom.us xxxxxx")

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    name_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "input-for-name")))

    name_field.click()
    name_field.send_keys("ENTER NAME HERE")

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("Name input field not found. Website may have changed structure.")
finally:
    driver.quit()

